# Reposition UIButtons inside customCell on InterfaceOrientation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiinterfaceorientation

Im using a custom tableviewcell, with 3 buttons.

I set the Frame of the buttons inside the layoutSubviews method, in my custom cell :

```
-(void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    CGRect frame;
    if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation))
    {
        frame = CGRectMake(310, 7, 55, 35);
        _prod.frame = frame;
        
        frame = CGRectMake(365, 7, 55, 35);
        _leva.frame = frame;
        
        frame = CGRectMake(220, 4, 65, 65);
        _imageButton.frame = frame;
    }
    else{
        frame = CGRectMake(150, 7, 55, 35);
        _prod.frame = frame;
        
        frame = CGRectMake(205, 7, 55, 35);
        _leva.frame = frame;
       
        frame = CGRectMake(120, 4, 65, 65);
        _imageButton.frame = frame;
    }
}
```

the problem is, when the user scrolls the table view, after changing the orientation, to Landscape for example, all the buttons, goes back to the old Portrait position. 
And heres how i initialize the cells:

```
LojaCell *cell = (LojaCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: @"LojaCell"];
if(cell == nil) cell = [[LojaCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"LojaCell"];
```

Answer (score 0):

you might have to add the same orientation-sensitive code to cellForRowAtIndexPath: so that they load in the correct place if the tableview reloads or recreates the cells. Because you are using dequeueReusableCells, which removes offscreen cells for performance, that might explain the behaviour when scrolling.